# Laravel / Zend Barcode render strange codebar

Tags: laravel, zend-framework, barcode

I have some problem with zend barcode, i use laravel 5.7 and when i wrote a simple code from documentary (below)

```
use Zend\Barcode\Barcode;

$barcodeOptions = ['text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK'];

$rendererOptions = [];

Barcode::render(
    'code39',
    'image',
    $barcodeOptions,
    $rendererOptions
);
```

This is part of my result:

�PNG  IHDR>��h� pHYs���+IDATx����r� PO�����©c�9ISֺ2�@��Y֮eY��������#���=E���V��ܪ3~��_/�}�<��ϑ����푱�޻������]��>Ɂ��@Br !9��HH$$�    Ɂ��@Br !9��HH$$�   Ɂ��@Br !9��HH$$�   Ɂ��@Br !9��HH$$�   Ɂ��@Br !9��HH$$�   Ɂ��@Br !9��HH$$�

looks like i have wrong charset but i don't know how fix it. I have server from digitalocean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser is receiving the PNG and being told it is a text file. You need to specify a [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types). In this case, that MIME type would be `image/png`.

For example:

```
return response()
    ->view('embedded')
    ->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
```